# Call to a member function on a non-object error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am [using this code here](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query) to get information from my Minecraft server. It did as expected using a static .php file, but after moving it to a local copy of WordPress, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function GetPlayers() on a non-object in C:\...\home.php on line 125
```

I am fairly sure I moved everything correctly. On line 125, is this snippet of code:

```
<div class="online group container">
      <h2> Who's online </h2>
          <?php if( ( $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( ) ) !== false ): ?>
          <?php foreach( $Players as $Player ): ?>
          <div class="player">                      
            <span class="p"  title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $Player ); ?>" data-player="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $Player ); ?>">☺</span>
          </div><!-- /.player -->
```

This is how I called the PHP class in header.php, before the doctype.

```
<?php

  define( 'MQ_SERVER_ADDR', '108.170.3.138:25643' );
  define( 'MQ_SERVER_PORT', 25643 );
  define( 'MQ_TIMEOUT', 1 );

  require bloginfo('template_url') . 'inc/avatars/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

  $Timer = MicroTime( true );
  $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

  try
  {
    $Query->Connect( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT );
  }
  catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
  {
    $Error = $e->getMessage();
   echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
  }

?>
```

It's weird because it works great without being on WordPress, but once I moved it, it broke. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How to include home.php from header.php ?

Comment: Check how to $Query has pass to <?php if( ( $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( ) ) !== false ): ?>

Comment: header.php is being included in home.php, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Please, show how to you include header.php ?

Comment: home.php has get_header() function to include header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function which will return Query in

function.php

```
function get_MQ_Query() {
  define( 'MQ_SERVER_ADDR', '108.170.3.138:25643' );
  define( 'MQ_SERVER_PORT', 25643 );
  define( 'MQ_TIMEOUT', 1 );

  require bloginfo('template_url') . 'inc/avatars/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

  $Timer = MicroTime( true );
  $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

  try
  {
    $Query->Connect( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT );
  }
  catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
  {
    $Error = $e->getMessage();
   echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
  }
  return $Query;
}
```

home.php

```
$Query = get_MQ_Query();
?><div class="online group container">
  <h2> Who's online </h2>
```

Comment: Would'nt advice to use global variables

Comment: See more here: 1. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-global-variables  2. http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @Bono, well, he have to create function which will return $Query

Comment: Thanks! the error is gone! Could this be any thing related to why my jQuery plugins keep saying 'Object [object Object] has no method' when being called?